# Hacking default math alphabet(-s?), for both normal and bold \mathversion's

Tags: math-mode, bold, greek, alphabet

I am trying to replace the greek math letters with another font, while keeping the rest of the math font intact. My solution so far works nice for the normal math version, but not for bold. I know that the font has both weights in italic. How do I make this change apply to `\mathversion{bold}` as well?

[image: PDF output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{custom}{LGR}{bodoni}{m}{it}

\newcommand*{\msym}[2]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathord}{custom}{#2}}

\msym{\alpha}{"61}
\msym{\beta}{"62}
\msym{\gamma}{"67}
\msym{\delta}{"64}
\msym{\epsilon}{"65}
\msym{\zeta}{"7A}
\msym{\eta}{"68}
\msym{\theta}{"6A}
\msym{\iota}{"69}
\msym{\kappa}{"6B}
\msym{\lambda}{"6C}
\msym{\mu}{"6D}
\msym{\nu}{"6E}
\msym{\xi}{"78}
\msym{\omicron}{"6F}
\msym{\pi}{"70}
\msym{\rho}{"72}
\msym{\sigma}{"73}
\msym{\tau}{"74}
\msym{\upsilon}{"75}
\msym{\phi}{"66}
\msym{\chi}{"71}
\msym{\psi}{"79}
\msym{\omega}{"77}
\msym{\varsigma}{"63}

\newcommand*{\mylgralphabet}{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta
\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi(o)
\pi\rho\sigma\tau\upsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega\varsigma}

\begin{document}

{\mathversion{normal}$\mylgralphabet - (normal)$}

{\mathversion{bold}$\mylgralphabet - (bold)$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{custom}{LGR}{bodoni}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{custom}{bold}{LGR}{bodoni}{b}{it}

\newcommand*{\msym}[2]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathalpha}{custom}{#2}}

\msym{\alpha}{"61}
\msym{\beta}{"62}
\msym{\gamma}{"67}
\msym{\delta}{"64}
\msym{\epsilon}{"65}
\msym{\zeta}{"7A}
\msym{\eta}{"68}
\msym{\theta}{"6A}
\msym{\iota}{"69}
\msym{\kappa}{"6B}
\msym{\lambda}{"6C}
\msym{\mu}{"6D}
\msym{\nu}{"6E}
\msym{\xi}{"78}
\msym{\omicron}{"6F}
\msym{\pi}{"70}
\msym{\rho}{"72}
\msym{\sigma}{"73}
\msym{\tau}{"74}
\msym{\upsilon}{"75}
\msym{\phi}{"66}
\msym{\chi}{"71}
\msym{\psi}{"79}
\msym{\omega}{"77}
\msym{\varsigma}{"63}

\newcommand*{\mylgralphabet}{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta
\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi(o)
\pi\rho\sigma\tau\upsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega\varsigma}

\begin{document}

{\mathversion{normal}$\mylgralphabet - (normal)$}

{\mathversion{bold}$\mylgralphabet - (bold)$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just added one line